# Pandas: Groupby improvement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Anyone got tricks to speed up or eliminate the for loop and still come up the with same tuple keyed dictionary of dataframes?

```
import pandas as pd

foo1 = (['LABEL1','LABEL1','LABEL2','LABEL2'])
foo2 = ([5,5,6,6])
foo3 = ([1,1,2,3])

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([foo1,foo2,foo3], 
                                  names=['ifoo1','ifoo2','ifoo3'])

initFrame = pd.DataFrame({'bar1': [5,6,5,6],
                          'bar2': ['a','b','c','d'],
                          'bar3': [11,22,33,44],
                          'bar4': [1,2,1,3]}, index=index)

finDict = {}
grouper = initFrame.groupby(level=('ifoo2', 'ifoo3'))
for name, group in grouper:
    finDict.update({name:group})
```

Comment: Seems not obvious, but is the `dict` of `DataFrame` the final expected result ? Because is not a quite common structure. What is the usage of this structure ? For example `initFrame.reset_index(level=0).to_dict(orient='index')` gives a `dict` of `dict` indexed by tuple, but you expect `DataFrame`

Comment: finDict is the expected result, it is just a dictionary, tuple keys and df values.

Comment: you need to do a traversal of grouper to generate each sub dataframe: your code is fine